# Using Membership class in repository classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I create a repository class like this:

```
public class ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository
    {

        private Guid _userIdentifier = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        ....
    }
```

Whenever I am not logged in to my site and I try to navigate to an `[Authorize]` filtered page, it will throw an error (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`) on my repository class at `private Guid _userIdentifier = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;`

The filter attribute does not catch the fact that the user is not authenticated.  What would be the best way to be able to get the current logged in user's `ProviderUserKey` within the repository class so it can be used all over the repository class?

Comment: Not an answer but I'm not sure your repository should depend on the Membership class.  Why wouldn't you pass in a user ID to the appropriate methods instead?

Comment: @DStanley just felt like passing UserId into a bunch of methods might be redundant, seemed cleaner to have it in the repository, but if its flawed then i guess ill have to change my methods.

Comment: what should the result of the query be when the user is not logged in?

Comment: "Flawed" may be strong - you could improve it by having an `IMembershipProvider` or some interface that would decouple your repository.  Do some research on Dependency Injection and decide for yourself.

Comment: @Iboshuizen The profile repository isnt used in any parts of the site that allows unauthorized users, but typing that out makes me realize that itd probably be better to just pass in a guid and have a private variable in my controller and pass it in every time, probably a better solution to this because my classes can be used in non authenticated situations as well.

Answer (score -1):

Inversion of control please.

It is not the responsibility of a Repository to go hunt for a user identifier. Anyway, you are actually assigning a value to a private member in the declaration space. I know C# lets you do this, but check how this code gets compiled under the cover and get into the habit of coding it that way. In the end, declarations should just be declarations.

I would need to see your calling code in order to help your further. Also, you're not mentioning what is the type of your membership provider.

Comment: -1 a) You do not really provide an alternative solution. b) The membership provider type do not matter.

Comment: A) The alternative solution was not not assign values in variable initialization but to actually look at his compiled code to understand his error...  b) Yes the type matters. You do realize that GetUser() is Abstract right?